# Spring Data Mongo Reads Load Balancing in Replication Setup?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

What does it mean to have application.properties file include multiple mongo db nodes like:

```
spring.data.mongodb.url=mongodb://endpoint1, endpoint2, endpoint3/db
```

I would like comments on Load Balancing e.g Round Robin and how well this is naturally integrated with the MongoDB replication High Availability Setup.

Comment: It is a seed list from which you can connect to the replica set if other members are down or respond quicker. Also What do you mean by load balancing a replica set?

Comment: By load balancing a replica set, I meant balancing reads across individual nodes in the replica set. SInce Mongo is single write master.

Comment: There is no automatic load balancing. You can set a read preference for individual queries, however, differing from the default/global read preference. You have to decide which queries can be answered with only eventual consistency.

Comment: Markus, how do I set the read preference? I use springs auto generated queries.